# grep for a variable excluding the dot sign

Tags: bash, grep

I want to grep a variable excluding those that start with a dot sign. However choosing the -w option for entire word doesn't include a dot sign so instead of only selecting 4 55 48 it also selects 0.4 0.55 5.48.

e.g. $var=1565

input

```
A 3.00027 1565    
B 3.00026 1565    
C -1.1565 5000
```

desired output

```
A 3.00027 1565    
B 3.00026 1565
```

I have seen solutions to `grep` for an exact pattern starting with grep, but that doesn't work with a variable.

I have tried adding a space sign before the variable as in lines below but it doesn't give desired output either.

```
grep -E -w " $var" input.txt > output.txt #results in empty output
grep -E -w "[:space:]|$var" input.txt > output.txt # gives solutions that include the dot sign
```

Comment: You might want to read the man page about what -w does and what it does and does not match.  You could also have a look at word boundaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
grep -E "(^|\s)$var(\s|$)"
```

Comment: That is also for whitespace?
I don't have whitespace also after my variable, only before,after the variable I have tabulator.

Comment: Modify as needed, but the solution is sound.

Comment: (^|\s)$var gave me output with all lines from file, have I modified it wrongly?

Comment: @katarina this solution prints only lines where the `$var` content is either enclosed by white-spaces (space, tab) OR theyre at the beginning or the end of line. So, it is an **good solution** and test it before you start modifying it. From your example it selects the desired output.

Comment: I had tested it without modifying it and it gave me empty output. My files for sure contain blank spaces before the pattern and tabulators after the pattern so I don't know where the problem could be.
But thanks for explaining me the meaning of it, good to know for future.

Comment: @katarina - Assuming 'var' is still set to 1565, the example is as above and using your modification, I am returning only the first 2 lines.  It would not be possible to return the third line as a period is neither the start of a line nor white space.

Comment: Sorry, I had a syntax error due to something else, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Because me like perl-regexes, i would to use overcomplicated regex:

```
grep -P "((?<=^)|(?<=\s))$var(?=(\s|$))"
```

the regex will work even with `-o` and returns just the number without any spaces or like around. (uses non-caturing groups)

Answer (score 0):

```
var=1565
cat input.txt|uniq|grep -E ^[A-Z]+.*$var >output.txt
```

here you go, make a pattern and match it with **uniq** filtered lines. 
The desired pattern to match those lines is ***1565**. I just stored that pattern in a variable.

test this out

```
awk -F " " "{if(\$3==$var){print(\$0);}}" input.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it still includes patterns starting with a dot.

Comment: try this out now. You need the line which is starting with capital alphabets and ends with the var value. is it?

Comment: @katarina can you please post your worst case?

Comment: No I do not need a line that starts with capital alphabets, the first column is irrelevant. It is only important that it contains $var value as a separate word. However, option -w doesn't count for dot sign.

Comment: what do you mean by worst case?

Comment: worst case? the unwanted output you get or the output you don't want to get.

Comment: worst case is when it prints out all the three lines from input.txt in the question instead of the two desired lines from output.txt

Comment: I think that you need the 2nd column. is it? those 3.00026 etc?

Comment: however the command i wrote gives the same thing which you specified as desired output.

Comment: First and second column contain many various contents, the pattern I want to match is in the third column, 1565.

Comment: What about awk? you can easily match if you are knowing the column number

Comment: to pipe awk and grep or solely awk?

Comment: just awk is enough. check that out now.